# Using conditional if/else logic with pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

My dataframe called `pw2` looks something like this, where I have two columns, pw1 and pw2, which are probability of wins. I'd like to perform some conditional logic to create another column called `WINNER` based off `pw1` and `pw2`.

```
+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|          Name1          |     pw1     |   Name2   |     pw2     |
+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| Seaking                 | 0.517184213 | Lickitung | 0.189236181 |
| Ferrothorn              | 0.172510623 | Quagsire  | 0.260884258 |
| Thundurus Therian Forme | 0.772536272 | Hitmonlee | 0.694069408 |
| Flaaffy                 | 0.28681284  | NaN       | NaN         |
+-------------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to do this conditionally in a function but I'm having some trouble.

- if `pw1` > `pw2`, populate with `Name1`
- if `pw2` > `pw1`, populate with `Name2`
- if `pw1` is populated but `pw2` isn't, populate with `Name1`
- if `pw2` is populated but `pw1` isn't, populate with `Name2`

But my function isn't working - for some reason checking if a value is null isn't working.

```
def final_winner(df):
    # If PW1 is missing and PW2 is populated, Pokemon 1 wins
    if df['pw1'] = None and df['pw2'] != None:
        return df['Number1']
    # If it's the same thing but the other way around, Pokemon 2 wins
    elif df['pw2'] = None and df['pw1'] != None:
        return df['Number2']
    # If pw2 is greater than pw1, then Pokemon 2 wins
    elif df['pw2'] > df['pw1']:
        return df['Number2']
    else
        return df['Number1']

pw2['Winner'] = pw2.apply(final_winner, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use `apply`, which is very slow. Use `np.where`

```
pw2 = df.pw2.fillna(-np.inf)
df['winner'] = np.where(df.pw1 > pw2, df.Name1, df.Name2)
```

Once `NaN`s always lose, can just `fillna()` it with `-np.inf` to yield same logic.

---

Looking at your code, we can point out several problems. First, you are comparing `df['pw1'] = None`, which is invalid python syntax for comparison.  You usually want to compare things using `==` operator. However, for `None`, it is recommended to use `is`, such as `if variable is None: (...)`. However again, you are in a `pandas/numpy` environment, where there actually several values for null values (`None`, `NaN`, `NaT`, etc).

So, it is preferable to check for nullability using `pd.isnull()` or `df.isnull()`.

Just to illustrate, this is how your code should look like:

```
def final_winner(df):
    if pd.isnull(df['pw1']) and not pd.isnull(df['pw2']):
        return df['Name1']
    elif pd.isnull(df['pw2']) and not pd.isnull(df['pw1']):
        return df['Name1']
    elif df['pw2'] > df['pw1']:
        return df['Name2']
    else:
        return df['Name1']

df['winner'] = df.apply(final_winner, axis=1)
```

But again, definitely use `np.where`.